ASP.NET MVC - Search Functionality
I've implemented a search to filter out records by LastName, but it doesn't work; basically it does nothing. I have Googled and tried using several code sample but not been able to use them since I get syntax errors. I have also tried an article here text but it also did not work for me.
How do I get the search to work?
Index.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<DEntry.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Student Administration</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Students", "Students", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="nameToFind" name="nameToFind">
        <input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit" />
    </div>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>

        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>

</tr>
    }

</table> 

Student.cs:
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DEntry.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<int> StudentID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

StudentsController.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DEntry.Models;

namespace DEntry.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private EISEntities db = new EISEntities();

        // GET: Students
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Students.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Students/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Student Student = db.Students.Find(id);

            if (Student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(Student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Students/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,StudentID,FirstName,LastName")] Student Student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Students.Add(Student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(Student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Student Student = db.Students.Find(id);

            if (Student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(Student);
        }

        // POST: Students/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,StudentID,FirstName,LastName")] Student Student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(Student);
        }

        // GET: Students/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Student Student = db.Students.Find(id);

            if (Student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(Student);
        }

        // POST: Students/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Student Student = db.Students.Find(id);
            db.Students.Remove(Student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //Get Action for rendering view
        public ActionResult SearchAct()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchAct(string nameToFind)
        {
            ViewBag.SearchKey = nameToFind;
            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}

I have also tried an article here text but it also did not work for me.

What error you get

Your public ActionResult SearchAct() action doesn't actually do anything... so where is this "search code" you claim to have written?

I am new to MVC, copied this code from an article when searched in Google.  The page renders all data correctly form the database which was my original goal but now I want to add search to it.

@khurj I suggest you first attempt to read-through and understand any code you copy-and-paste from the Internet, so you can understand what it does and doesn't do, before you copy-and-paste malicious code into your projects...

Dai,  I copied and pasted good code from Microsoft site and understood what it was doing to render data on the page.  I am only struggling with adding the search to the existing code and I have already mentioned in my previous post. If you can’t help then no need to respond.

"I have also tried an article here text but it also did not work for me" What did you tried and didn't work, share that code.


I've implemented a search to filter out records by LastName, but it
doesn't work; basically it does nothing. I have Googled and tried
using several code sample but not been able to use them since I get
syntax errors. I have also tried an article here text but it also did
not work for me.
How do I get the search to work?

Actually, your shared code is not adequate for searching functionality as you are missing couple of important stuff.
For instance, in order to search by anything you should have a parameter within your controller action in your scenario "Index" which is missing.
Apart from that in your code its not clear in your method SearchAct what ViewBag.SearchKey is doing?
Another important thing is, you are not sending any search request from your view. Basically, you would need another form submit operation which should have contains your search key usually using name="searchString" attribute along with the value using viewData or viewBag.
Finally, with the submitted search key, you need to search on top your student list. That's all you need.
Let's have a look in practice, how we could achieve that
Demo Class:
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

Controller:
public class StudentSearchController : Controller
{
    private List<Student> GetDemoStudents()
    {
        return new List<Student>
    {
        new Student { Id = 1, StudentID = 101, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
        new Student { Id = 2, StudentID = 102, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith" },
        new Student { Id = 3, StudentID = 103, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Johnson" },
        new Student { Id = 4, StudentID = 104, FirstName = "Emily", LastName = "Davis" },
        new Student { Id = 5, StudentID = 105, FirstName = "David", LastName = "Brown" },
        new Student { Id = 6, StudentID = 106, FirstName = "Sarah", LastName = "Wilson" },
        new Student { Id = 7, StudentID = 107, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Miller" },
        new Student { Id = 8, StudentID = 108, FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Taylor" },
        new Student { Id = 9, StudentID = 109, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Anderson" },
        new Student { Id = 10, StudentID = 110, FirstName = "Laura", LastName = "Thomas" }
    };
    }
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var students = GetDemoStudents();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                                           || s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                           || s.StudentID.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                               .OrderBy(s => s.LastName) 
                               .ToList();
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentSearch = searchString;

        return View(students);
    }
}

View:
@model IEnumerable<Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
}

<h2>Students</h2>

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")">
    <p>
        Search: <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewBag.CurrentSearch" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.StudentID</td>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Note: Here I am using @ViewBag.CurrentSearch, however, you could use @ViewData[""]" as well.
Output:



Note: Please refer to this official document for additional information.

I have modified the code slightly to add sort functionality.  When I Hover mouse over to the column "Last Name", it is underlined but still the icon is "I" instead of a Hand and the data is not sorted.  I am trying to add code here but it errors out due to characters limit.

What did you mean? This was written for teching you how to implement search functionality, Not sure what do you need in sorting. If you want to change the order then use .OrderBy(s => s.LastName) which is available in linq query.

It seems my first response to you is not showing up here.  I responded by saying "Thank you, it seems to be working fine".  And then I added 2nd comment that you saw related to sorting.  The Code *** <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName) *** displays link in the column header but it is not clickable.  I had the exact same problem when I added the links for "Edit", "Delete" in the last column; and to fix it, I changed it to use @Html ActionLink to get it to work but I do not know how to get this sort link to work.

I have fixed the issue by changing that line of code to...  @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }).  Thank you for your support.

You are welcome and glad to assist you on this.
